# PHP/Jquery Ajax Return SQLite string

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, sqlite

I have the following Ajax request:

```
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getContent.php",
            dataType: "text",
            data: { "contentid": contentID },
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("Received: " + data );
            }
        });
    }
```

Which is sending a single value to my PHP script at getContent.php

The getContent.php is very simple, I think. It contains:

```
<?php 
// Set up connection to sqlite
try {
    $myPDO = new PDO('sqlite:freezy.sqlite');
 }  catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to get DB handle: " . $e->getMessage() . "\n";
    exit;
}

$id = $_POST['contentid'];

// Prepare an update statement
$sql = "select contentBlock from content where contentId  = :contentIDTarget";

// formalise the statement
$stmt = $myPDO->prepare($sql);

// passing values to the parameters
$stmt->bindValue(':contentIDTarget', $id);

// Execute the update
$result = $stmt->execute();

echo $result;

?>
```

This sql works fine when tested in a slqite test tool against the same database.

When I attempt to use this however, all I see in the console log on the
"Received: " line is:

Received: 1

What I was expecting to see was something like:
Received:

Just some test text

Because the result should contain a chunk of content that was placed in there from tinyMCE.

What am I missing? Would greatly appreciate a steer, please.

Answer (score 2):

Your statement...

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

will only return a boolean value. So seeing a '1' is a good thing as it means it worked.

So you need to return the actual results.
You could try something like...

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Which translates to something like...

```
// Execute the update

$stmt->execute();
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo $result;
```

or `echo $result['contentBlock'];`

It all depends on how you want to use it.

Does that help any?

Comment: Thanks @TimBrownlaw - much appreciated!

I am now using:      

    // Execute the update
    $stmt->execute();    
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo $result['contentBlock'];

and in the ajax request I am using:

 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "getContent.php",
                data: { "contentid": contentID },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log("Received: " + data );
                }
            });
        }

But I'm getting a 500 server error. Still checking...